# How to filter from a list of values using OnClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

**Scenario:** As mentioned in the below structure those are the elements which we have in our Website and Database. So when i click on Apple from website it selects apple and we can select how many or which kind of apple's a customer needs and does the same for the below fruits, But when we select "Citrus 1" 
or "Citrus 2" it always selects the Option as Citrus and hence saves it under citrus.

**My requirements**: I need a Jquery which selects the correct selection from the below list when i click on that event.

**Example:**

```
<Option Number="01">Apple   </Option>
<Option Number="02">Banana  </Option>
<Option Number="03">Citrus  </Option>
<Option Number="04">Citrus 1</Option>
<Option Number="05">Citrus 2</Option>
```

Comment: do you mean group ? [HTML <optgroup> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Comment: `$("option:selected").Number`
Use this value which would give you 01, 02 or 05. And perform your database operations as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Option Number="01">Apple   </Option>
<Option Number="02">Banana  </Option>
<optgroup label="Citrus">
  <Option Number="03">Citrus 1</Option>
  <Option Number="04">Citrus 2</Option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: How about i want to search from the same list, without adding labels.

Comment: optGroup will help, since if you dont know how much subcategory will come inside a category....also it is being dynamic